# Probability Distribution of Binary Operation Applied to Elements of Two Populations

Tags: probability, estimation, sampling

Given two populations from which one can draw finite samples, how does one estimate the probability density of the result of some binary operation applied to elements of the two populations?

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is that I have finite samples from 3 separate populations. Call them `A`, `B` and `C`. I want to estimate the probability density of `Q`, which consists of values, `q`, calculated as

```
q = a - b - c
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` are particular members of `A`, `B`, and `C` respectively.

Populations `A`, `B`, and `C` are independent and particular samples of one population have no special relation to particular samples from another. I want to estimate the probability density of `Q` but direct samples of `Q` are not available. Right now I'm generating samples of `Q` using the Cartesian product of samples of `A`, `B`, and `C`. I'm not sure if this is valid because the generated samples of `Q` are not independent, i.e. each value sampled from `A` is used to generate multiple samples of `Q`.

One alternative would be to randomly pair the samples from `A`, `B`, and `C`. That would produce a valid sampling of `Q` but it also produces a much smaller sample size.

What is the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

So basically you q is a function of $a$, $b$ and $c$ and you want to calculate the probability density of $q= g(a, b, c)$. This pretty standard so you can Google it or check any text book. The general technique is to marginalize on $q$: generally you are given density of joints, here due to independence, you know it is product form, ie, $f(a, b, c)= f(a)f(b)f(c)$ where $f(x)$ is its density function. Now, you have to marginalize by integrating over b, c and plugging q+b+c for a: $f(q)= \int_{-\infty}^ {+\infty} f(q+b+c, b, c) ~db~dc$

Shortcut: The density function of the summation of two independent RVs is given by the convolution of the densities, so here: $f(q)= f(a)*f(-b)*f(-c)$ where $*$ is convolution.

Comment: With finite samples, where the true densities are not known, this implies calculating values of q using the Cartesian product of the a, b, and c samples followed by density estimation, right? Your answer makes sense for working with probability densities but I feel funny about the apparently large sample size yet "lumpy" distributions this creates with finite samples.

Comment: I think I missed the part that you want to reconstruct $f(q)$ from samples. If that is what you are trying to do, you have two alternatives: 1) If you can assume you know the parametric distributions of the original RVs, then, you can come up with the parametric $f(q)$ and estimate its parameters off of samples of $q$ based on original samples. b) going fully blind and assuming nothing about the parametric forms, then your the fact that you know that $q$ is a function of three other RVs is not much of a help. I might still be missing sth though...